# Scala - error "value map is not a member of"

Tags: scala, for-loop, for-comprehension

Using Scala, I have got this error "value map is not a member of chemins.Point"
point <- segment.to

Here is my code :

```
package chemins

case class Point(name: String, x: Long, y: Long)

case class Segment(from: Point, to: Point) {
  def distance: Double = {

    math.sqrt((from.x - to.x)*(from.x - to.x) + (from.y - to.y)*(from.y - to.y))
  }

}

case class Path(segments: Vector[Segment]) {

  def length: Double = {

    (for {

      segment <- segments

    } yield segment.distance).sum

  }

  def stops : Vector[Point] = {

    for {
      segment <- segments
      point <-  segment.to
    } yield point
  }


}
```

From my previous search, it seems to come from the fact that "to" has no generator but I have no clues if it's relevant.

Thanks !

Comment: What is the `point <- segment.to` supposed to iterate over? Did you mean `for { segment <- segments } yield segment.to`?

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html

Comment: Thanks ! It indeed woks. I'm not sure to understand the difference between the 2 proposition. I need to go back to understand how for use the Flatmap. Have a nice day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at the `chemins` api, you most likely want

```
for { segment <- segments } yield segment.to
```

or

```
for { 
  segment <- segments
  point = segment.to
} yield point
```

Trying to use `segment.to` as a generator makes no sense, because it's not a collection or a `.map`-pable entity.

Also note that this for-comprehension reduces to

```
segments.map(_.to)
```